# What is the correct mysql (relational) database design structure for

Tags: mysql, relational-database, normalization

I have a table in my database called `Resource`. This has common information about a resource (a resource could be an article, a static web link, a YouTube video, or any number of other types).

For my example:

#### Table: resource

```
primary key - id,
column - type,
column - title,
column - description,
column - created_on,
column - updated_on
```

#### Table: resource_video

```
primary key - id,
column - youtube_id (spose this could be the primary key, but not relevant in the question).
column - ...
```

#### Table: resource_weblink

```
primary key - id,
column - url
column - ...
```

So essentially the `resource` table contains the generic (pertains to all resources), columns, and then tables are set up to hold `resource_type` specific data. What is the best (normalized) way to create relationships between `resource` and `resource_type`.

My first instinct is that it should be a one to one identifying relationship between the two tables with a foreign key of `resource_id` in the `resource_video` and `resource_weblink` tables, or would there be a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make the primary key of each `resource_*` table have a foreign key constraint to the `id` column of `resource`. There's no need for a separate `id` for each resource subtype. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315692/table-relationship-for-subtypes) for an example of how to do this (look at the SupportSystem hierarchy in the accepted answer).

Comment: So essentially I was on the right path with a slightly different approach of using the id in the resource table as the primary key in the resource_* table.  A side note, I could eliminate the resource.type column altogether as it would be irrelevant as well.  I think that was where I was confusing myself.  Correct path, with a few unnecessary columns.  Thank you!

Comment: No, you can't eliminate resource.type. It's highly relevant for data integrity. Look at how the "pub_type" column works in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969133/database-design-problem/4970646#4970646